# Posso levar as perguntas e respostas do SOpt para outros fóruns?

Tags: debate, conteúdo, licença

A questão é sobre visibilidade de conhecimento, vocês acham que é legal abranger perguntas que foram respondidas aqui e trazer como "curiosidade" em outros locais como perguntas interessantes?

Obviamente, marcando a fonte de cada resposta.

Ou isso seria me apropriar do conhecimento do site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está vendo ali no canto inferior direito do site a licença que ele adota?

[image: Print do Creative Commons]

Clicou lá para ver [o que é a licença Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.pt_BR)?

Então pode compartilhar sim onde quiser desde que coloque um *link* para o original deixando bem claro que há um autor daquilo.

Eu faço isso, [principalmente no Quora](https://pt.quora.com/profile/Antonio-Maniero/answers).